# Up grading from 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to  follow your procedure to install on a none pae machine. 12.04 installed OK but when I tried to get update to move to 13 I get an error:
Err Upgrade tool signature
   404 Not found[IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
I have done this before and it always worked

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 13.04 and 13.10 have reached the **end of life**. Try 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

13.x has reached end of life, when it comes to installing 14.04 on a non pae machine just start booting the live image, and when it comes to an imade of a man and a keyboard press f6 then choose language>yourlanguage then add `forcepae` to the end of the boot options line and it should work, or if it doesn't then install lubuntu or xubuntu first then install the ubuntu unity desktop after.